# setting values for nested json array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath

I have a nested JSON document , I want to set a particular value in the embedded JSON Array,

For Example:-

```
{
"name":"Jack",
"Address":{
    "secondaryAddress":[{"name":"JOHN's Address",
                       "street":"new ave",
                        "city":"Canada",
                        "mobile":123456789
                       },
                       {"name":"Selena's Address",
                       "street":"second ave",
                        "city":"Canada",
                        "mobile":987654321
                       },
                        {"name":"Jack's Address",
                       "street":"third ave",
                        "city":"Canada"
                       }],
           "primaryAddress":{},
          }
}
```

I want to change the mobile number from 987654321 to 456789123 in that particular secondaryAddress object which has mobile number as 987654321.

i am using jsonpath in my project to get / set values 
To get i would use :-

`$.Address.secondaryAddress[*].mobile`

which would return a array of mobile numbers like:-

```
[
 123456789,
 987654321
]
```

similarly for set too,

but i am not sure how to go ahead with this scenario where i want to set a particular object in array.

I tried using this but it still **sets the value for all array objects** :-

`DocumentContext cxt = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
cxt.set("$.Address.secondaryAddress[*].mobile",456789123,Criteria.where("$.Address.secondaryAddress[*].mobile").is("987654321");`

Please Help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.Address.secondaryAddress.[?(@.mobile=='987654321')]
```

Above jsonpath query will give you particular secondaryAddress node with mobile = 987654321
Use below expression to set the new mobile value-

```
$.Address.secondaryAddress.[?(@.mobile=='987654321')].mobile
```

Comment: i am able to get the values using filters, How to set that particulat object using this?